# Angular js ui-bootstrap pagination link not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using ui-bootstrap paginator for server side pagination but the pagination links doesn't seem to work. I'm using Laravel rest api as backend to fetch data from server. First set of data are displayed but when i click on page 2 nothing happens

My angular controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, Api, flash) {
$scope.flash = flash;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 2;
$scope.result = [];
$scope.resultUser = function() {
    if ($routeParams.id) {
        $scope.CurrentValue = Api.Users.get({
            id: $routeParams.id
        });
    } else {
        $scope.CurrentValue = new Api.Users();
        Api.Users.query(function(response) {
            $scope.result = response.result.data;
            $scope.totalPages = response.result.last_page;
            $scope.resultCount = response.result.total;
        });
    }
};
$scope.resultUser();
})
```

My service

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Api', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return {
        Users: $resource('users/:id', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
            },
            post: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: true
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PATCH',
                id: '@id'
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        }),
        News: $resource('news/:id', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
            },
            post: {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: true
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PATCH',
                id: '@id'
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        }),
        Search: $resource('users/find', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        }),
    }
    }
])
```

Server side UserController

```
public function index() {
    $result = User::paginate($limit = 2);
    return Response::json(array('result' => $result->toArray()));
}
```

My view

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>s.n</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                    <pagination total-items="resultCount" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" 
                        boundary-links="true"items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">
                    </pagination>
                  <tr ng-repeat="result in result | filter : paginate">
                     <!-- <tr ng-repeat="result in result | filter:query "> -->
                      <div><%currentPage%> &nbsp;
                    <td>
                      <div class="action-checkbox">
                        <input id="<%result.id%>" type="checkbox" value="<%result.id%>" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(result.id) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(result.id)" />
                        <label for="<%result.id%>"></label>
                          <%result.id%>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%result.name%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%result.email%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <%result.username%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#/users/edit/<%result.id%>" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">edit</a>
                      <button ng-click="delete(result.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </div>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Can u share it in jsfiddle so that i can able to check from my end?